# FormData is null but file is ok

Tags: vue.js, axios, vuejs3, form-data

(front vuejs3 + axios | back nodejs + prisma sql)

I have a function to create a post. When I use it with postman it works.

[image]

But when I use it with frontend it returns me a formdata = null

On this.selectedFile, i have the file

can you help me please ?

```js
data () {
    return {
        title: '',
        content: '',
        userId: '',
        selectdFile: null,
    }
},
methods: {
    onFileSelected (event) {
        this.selectedFile = event.target.files[0];
        console.log(this.selectedFile);
    },
    async createPost() {
        const formData = new FormData();
        formData.append( 'image', this.selectedFile, this.selectedFile.name );

        console.log('ok')
        console.log(formData);
        const id = localStorage.getItem('userId');
        const response = await axios.post('http://localhost:3000/api/post', {
            title: this.title,
            content: this.content,
            userId: parseInt(id),
            attachment: formData,

        }, {
            headers: {
                Authorization: 'Bearer ' + localStorage.getItem('token')
            },
        });
        console.log(response);
    },
```

Voici le resultat :
[image]

Comment: Any errors or weird things in the Vue devtools? Like a CORS issue?

Comment: no error i have add a picture

Comment: You need to include all your other data properties in the `FormData` and use `axios.post(url, formData)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```js
const response = await axios.postForm(
  "http://localhost:3000/api/post",
  {
    title: this.title,
    content: this.content,
    userId: parseInt(id),
    attachment: this.selectedFile,
  },
  {
    headers: {
      Authorization: "Bearer " + localStorage.getItem("token"),
    },
  }
);
```

Comment: C:\Users\gbl\Documents\1-Dev\Openclassroom\P7_barbosalustano_geoffrey\P7\backend\controllers\post.js:38
                attachment: `${req.protocol}://${req.get('host')}/images/${req.file.filename}`,
                                                                                    ^

TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'filename')